# Scaling dynamic button

Tags: android, screen, scale, android-tablelayout

I am trying to add a large number of buttons in a row to a screen. The buttons are set in a TableLayout. I have searched multiple places like this:
[Calculate screen size in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888942/calculate-screen-size-in-android) trying to find a way to set the size of multiple buttons (between 1 and 9) so that they will all fit on one screen. The buttons are created dynamically like this:

```
    // put values into btn array
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        tr = new TableRow(this);
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            b = new Button(this);
            b.setOnClickListener(this);
            b.setText(bArray[j][i] + "");
            b.setTag(j + "," + i);
            tr.addView(b);
        }
        table.addView(tr);
    }
```

Note: the vars row and col are set to the same value (a number 1 through 9). The TableLayout is set inside a RelativeLayout in xml like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >


</TableLayout>
```

EDIT: the buttons are going horizontally.

Comment: What is your problem? What is the question? Why isn't it working, i.e. what do actually see vs. what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do a lot of different things. It is hard to tell exactly what you are going for from your question but I will throw out some options. (I don't know what way these buttons are going, so I am assuming vertical)

1. A simple way is to find the height and divide it by the number of buttons.  Something along the lines of `b.setHeight(this.getHeight()/numButtons)`
2. You can simply apply a wrap content attribute to the height of the buttons.  This will simply take up the minimum needed space.
3. Use a `ScrollView` so that you don't have to worry about heights at all.
4. Lastly, you can set each of the buttons to `match_parent` and set each of their `layout_weight`'s equal.  **I would recommend this method**.  Its probably the easiest and least error prone.

Carification on #4

With the buttons going horizontally, you are going to want to set the width of the buttons to `MATCH_PARENT` and the `layout_weight` to a constant number (eg 0.5).  This will make all of the buttons expand across the parent with an equal width.

Comment: Can you clarify number 4? If I have a Tablelayout inside a RelativeLayout you are saying that I should do something like this: TableLayout.LayoutParams lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); is that correct?

Comment: @Rilcon42 Yes, that should be fine, I have updated my post for more clarity, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Also, note the distinction between `layout_weight` and `layout_width`.